# Object doesn't support property or method 'success' in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to upload file using MVC4 with AngularJS and my file is upload to server successfully with below code but i can't able to get confirmation because of error. please check my all code which i have been done.

### My C# Controller Code

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SaveFiles(string description)
    {
        string Message, fileName, actualFileName;
        Message = fileName = actualFileName = string.Empty;
        bool flag = false;
        if (Request.Files != null)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];
            actualFileName = file.FileName;
            fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
            int size = file.ContentLength;
            try
            {
                string fPath = Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles/");
                DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(fPath);
                if (!d.Exists)
                {
                    d.Create();
                }
                file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), fileName));
                flag = true;
                Message = "success";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Message = "File upload failed! Please try again";
            }

        }
        return new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                Message = Message,
                Status = flag
            }
        };
    }
```

### Module.js

```
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

### Controller.js

```
    angular.module('myApp').controller('fileController', ["$scope", "FileUploadService", function ($scope, FileUploadService) {
    //Save File
    $scope.SaveFile = function () {        
        FileUploadService.UploadFile($scope.SelectedFileForUpload
                                     , $scope.FileDescription
            ).then(function (d) {
                console.log(d);
                alert(d.Message);
                ClearForm();
            }, function (e) {
                alert(e);
            });        
    }

}])
.factory('FileUploadService', function ($http, $q) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.UploadFile = function (file, description) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);
        formData.append("description", description);
        // debugger;
        var defer = $q.defer();
        try {
            debugger;
            $http.post("/Home/SaveFiles", formData,
                  {
                      withCredentials: true,
                      headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                      transformRequest: angular.identity
                  }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                      debugger;
                      console.log('success...');                      
                      defer.resolve(d);
                  }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
                      debugger;
                      console.log('error...');                      
                      defer.reject("File Upload Failed!");
                  });

        } catch (e) {
            debugger;
            console.log(e);
            console.log(e.message);
        }
        return defer.promise;
    }
    return fac;
});
```

### Error

```
**TypeError**: Object doesn't support property or method 'success'
   at fac.UploadFile (http://localhost:52240/myScript/Controller.js:92:13)
   at $scope.SaveFile (http://localhost:52240/myScript/Controller.js:52:9)
   at fn (Function code:2:138)
   at callback (http://localhost:52240/Scripts/angular.js:26994:17)
   at Scope.prototype.$eval (http://localhost:52240/Scripts/angular.js:18161:9)
   at Scope.prototype.$apply (http://localhost:52240/Scripts/angular.js:18261:13)
   at Anonymous function (http://localhost:52240/Scripts/angular.js:26999:17)
   at r.event.dispatch (http://localhost:52240/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:10259)
   at q.handle (http://localhost:52240/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3:8269)
```

Please help...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use then() instead of success() :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you are using angular version that is higher than 1.4 then `success` method is deprecated. use `then` to catch the promise.

```
$http.post("/Home/SaveFiles", formData,
                  {
                      withCredentials: true,
                      headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
                      transformRequest: angular.identity
                  }).then(function (response) {
                      debugger;
                      console.log('success...');                      
                      defer.resolve(response.data);
                  })
                  .catch(function (response) {
                     debugger;
                     console.log('error...');                      
                     defer.reject("File Upload Failed!");
                 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. it is working file but in this function error method is also deprecated so what else should i write instate of .error()? @sachila ranawaka

Comment: Use method .catch() instead of .error(). Or i thinks second callback from .then() catch error. (I prefer and i always used .catch())

Comment: like @nevradub mentioned, use the catch method. check the updated answer